# How is the readability of the "to be implemented" used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, readability

Thanks for your time, below sentence is a sales achievement written in the summary at the beginning of my resume:

> ...sealing the deals, settling the exclusive design architectures of the to be implemented two generations’ [Wireless Presentation Gateway](https://www.viewsonic.com/eu/products/archive/WPG-360) and led the projects to manage the products’ design, development, manufacturing, and shipping.

How is the readability of the "to be implemented" used in this sentence? A proofread company told me that it was grammatically correct, but it was not quite intuitive to read. Any suggestion or the usage here is just fine?

Here is another example I found online:

> [Poland new contract: KTC has been awarded the direct distribution service for the to be implemented satellite based (GNSS) ETC system.](https://www.erstegroup.com/en/research/report/en/SR207622)

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding what "Wireless Presentation Getaway" is, a concrete answer cannot be provided, but the proof-reading company seems to be correct. Consider hyphenating the [compound modifier](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen-with-compound-modifiers/) *(?)* to make it more comprehensible.

> [...] sealing the deals, settling the exclusive design architectures of the to-be-implemented [...]

---

Further reading:

> Hyphens' main purpose is to glue words together. They notify the reader that two or more elements in a sentence are linked. Although there are rules and customs governing hyphens, there are also situations when writers must decide whether to add them for clarity.

> Rule 1a. Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound adjective.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> - an off-campus apartment
> - state-of-the-art design
>
> > https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed comment.

The [Wireless Presentation Gateway](https://www.viewsonic.com/eu/products/archive/WPG-360) is an electronics product allowing a computer/laptop to wirelessly connect to an LCD projector or TV for displaying its video, images or computer data; other than its wireless displaying function, the product functions as a WiFi router for internet connection for the computers or laptops wirelessly connected to it. The product connects to an LCD projector or TV through a physical cable; The computers or laptops connect to the product wirelessly.

Comment: Here are more explanations and I hope this would help on giving a concert answer, thanks very much! :) The product was sold under an electronics consumer brand – ViewSonic – and my previous company designed and manufactured it for the brand, and this commercial deal between both was developed by me.

Comment: The use of the “to-be-implemented” was from the context that the brand bought the company’s product designing/manufacturing service and launched the product, which was equally the product was, from my point of view, implemented into the brand's product lines for them to sell to their market, this was the result of both companies’ cooperation and my business development and project management efforts.

Comment: Below is the full sentence of this achievement in my resume's beginning summary:

“...brought in a large electronics customer – ViewSonic – from scratch: cold-calling, business developing, sealing the deals, settling the exclusive design architectures of the to-be-implemented two generations’ [Wireless Presentation Gateway](https://www.viewsonic.com/eu/products/archive/WPG-360) and led the projects to manage the products’ design, development, manufacturing, and shipping.”

Thanks 

Comment: I wouldn't scare off the reader with techie talk so fast. Maybe "...sealing the deals, settling the exclusive architecture of a wireless gateway, and *leading* the projects to manage the *product* design, development, manufacturing, and shipping." The whole business of something to be implemented is unneeded. Who designs architecture for anything already done? Of course it's to be implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I really appreciate your time for giving advice.